# Katalon run all test suites on Test Suites folder

Tags: docker, jenkins, katalon-studio, katalon

I'm new to Katalon. 
I have a Katalon Project that looks like:

main project:

- foo1
- foo2
- Test Cases
- Test Suites

  - file1.ts
  - file2.ts
    ....
  - file.ts

So I would like to run all the test files in Test Suites folder on Jenkins with Docker container. I try with command: 
`katalonc -projectPath=./ -browserType="Chrome" -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/"`

But I got the error:

```
Caused by: com.kms.katalon.execution.exception.InvalidConsoleArgumentException: Test suite 'Test Suites/' not found.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the test suites you wish to execute in Jenkins to a test suites collection:

[image]

And add `-testSuiteCollectionPath="Test Suites/test sute collection 1"` to the command.